# What is the event handler for when user allows use of mic Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, permissions

So, I am having errors most likely resulting from the microphone not getting a stream until the permissions are set by the user.

```
function calls(){
    var call = peer.call("<? echo $room_id; ?>", window.localStream);
    step3(call);
}
```

This assumption stems from the fact that it only has an error occur, which refers to call being undefined, when the page is loading and the method is called. After the permissions are set, it has no problem. Is there an event handler that can run the function when the permissions are set for the microphone?

Comment: there is a callback to navigator.getUserMedia() that you can use. you can always try/catch if your lib doesn't expose the callback.

Comment: Would you please post your solution?

Comment: The solution involves getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, Success(), Failure()), and put the functions in the respected parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I forgot to post a solution:

```
 getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, Success(), Failure());
```

And you put the proper functions within their respected argument placeholders.